# Case-insensitive Search in SwiftData Predicate

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I’m trying to filter using `@Query` but I’m struggling with what I thought would be easy enough, i.e. a case-insensitive `Predicate` filter. Using this [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/sorting-query-results), I’ve written:

```
@Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
@Query private var users: [User]
// Start with a default "show all" filter
@State private var myFilter: Predicate<User> = #Predicate { aUser in aUser.name != "" }
@State private var searchTerm: String = ""

...

TextField("Search names...", text: $searchTerm)
    .onSubmit {
        if searchTerm.isEmpty {
            // Show all
            myFilter = #Predicate { aUser in aUser.name != "" }
        } else {
            myFilter = #Predicate { aUser in
                aUser.name.contains(searchTerm)
            }
        }
    }

// Pass the filter down to a `View` that can display just what we want
FUIUserView(sort: SortDescriptor(\User.name), filter: myFilter)
```

But this will only filter with case-sensitivity. I've also tried generating a `Regex` expression:

```
let search = (try? Regex("/(i?)(\(searchTerm))/")) ?? (try? Regex(""))!
myFilter = #Predicate { aUser in
    aUser.name.contains(search)
}
```

But this won't compile, instead throwing up:

`Static method 'build_contains' requires that 'Regex<AnyRegexOutput>' conform to 'Collection'`

I realise the Regex syntax is probably wrong, but the point is that I can't think of a way of sending a case-insensitive search expression to the `Predicate`s closure.

My work-around is to set the name (and any other member of `User` that I want to search) as `Private (set)` to prevent a client object directly setting the details, and then have a `func` that sets up transformed strings for use in a search:

```
extension User {
    func setSearchables(name: String) {
        self.name = name // This is displayed on the UI
        self.uppercasedName = name // This is never displayed but only used in the search code
    }
}
```

Then modify my SwiftUI code to:

```
TextField("Search names...", text: $searchTerm)
    .onSubmit {
        if searchTerm.isEmpty {
            // Show all
            myFilter = #Predicate { aUser in aUser.name != "" }
        } else {
            let ucSearchTerm = searchTerm.uppercased()
            myFilter = #Predicate { aUser in
                aUser.uppercasedName.contains(ucSearchTerm)
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this really my best logic, though? Is there a proper, case-insensitive way of searching that doesn't involve wasting a whole variable in the stored `User`?

Please note: I know I can filter without using `@Query` but I'm anticipating a large number of users and their associated details so I understand from other articles that `@Query(filter:_)` is the better way.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/predicate

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson, I've read that but I can't see how it fits with a solution except to suggest case-insensitivity isn't possible....? But please elaborate if I've mis-understood.

Comment: I read `caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)` on the linked page. Isn't what you're looking for? `aUser.name.caseInsensitiveCompare(searchTerm) == .orderSame`

Answer (score 1):

So the "Related Questions" section showed the same question. Oops.

A few clicks led me to:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/733215

Which shows a simple `localizedStandardContains(searchTerm)` will do the trick.